# Azure Mobile Service – Setting up development and production environments

Tags: azure, development-environment, azure-mobile-services, dev-to-production

I have one JavaScript backend Azure Mobile Service (AMS) with tables and APIs. I have been developing on that single instance of AMS for the last few months and now I want to create another instance of AMS as a live and production environment.

How do I replicate my current AMS development instance to be used as production AMS?

Answer (score 1):

Two options.

Manual:

- create a new service
- set your environment variables/configuration
- create the tables used in your table endpoints
- setup source control access (git)
- add a new remote in your source control
- push the code to the new remote

Automate:

- use CLI script to do all of the above. Details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-manage-command-line-interface/#how-to-create-a-mobile-service).